# Display round value of total amount in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am displaying total amount after GSt apply. When  total amount is 1497,after applying 18% gst i am getting 1766.46 amount. it is correct or we can round this amount as 1766 if yes,the how can i round this value in blade file as well as jquery.

```
<div class="mt-2">
    <span>
        <label><b>Total Amount</b></label>
    </span>
    <?php $total_buynow_amount=$getBuynowProduct->subtotal+($getBuynowProduct->subtotal*0.18)?>
    <span class="price-right buynow_total_price">
        {{number_format( $total_buynow_amount, 2) }}
    </span>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.buynow_qtyplus').click(function() { 
    var buynow_id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    var product_id=$(this).attr('data-value');
    var qty=$(this).prev().text();
    var input=$(this).prev();
    var subtotal=$(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find("span.buynow_subtotal").text();
    var input_subtotal=$(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find("span.buynow_subtotal");
    var sub_total=$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find("span.buynow_final_sub_total_price").text();
    var buynow_final_sub_total_price=$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find("span.buynow_final_sub_total_price");
    var total=$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find("span.buynow_total_price").text();
    var buynow_total_price=$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find("span.buynow_total_price");
    jQuery.ajax({
                  url: "{{ url('/buynow_qty_increment') }}",
                  method: 'get',
                  data: {
                     qty: qty,id:buynow_id,product_id:product_id
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                      if(result.status==1)
                      {
                          input.text(result.qty);
                          input_subtotal.text(result.subtotal);
                          buynow_final_sub_total_price.text(result.subtotal);
                          buynow_total_price.text(result.subtotal+(result.subtotal*0.18));
                          $(".modal-content").html("<div><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i><span style='margin-left:5px;'>" + result.message + "</span></div>");
                          $(".modal").modal("show");                      
                          setTimeout(function() {
                              $('.modal').modal('hide');                          
                          }, 3000); 
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          input.text(result.qty);
                          input_subtotal.text(result.subtotal);
                          buynow_final_sub_total_price.text(result.subtotal);
                          buynow_total_price.text(result.subtotal+(result.subtotal*0.18));
                      }
                  }});

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In blade.Do this:

```
{{round($data)}}
```

For jquery use:

```
Math.round(data)
```

Comment: Thanks it works Now i how can i do this in controller file?

Comment: @AshutoshMali for controller just use round($data);